# Corrupted database table with invalid query: what has it done and will it roll back?

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-warehouse

I made the error of running what should have been a quick update against my fact table (200M rows) with this:

```
update dbo.primary_fact
   set count_of_loan_obligors = o.n              
  from dbo.staging_fact f  
       -- notice that this is not the same table as the one in the update clause
       inner join ##Obligor_Count o
       on (f.time_dimension_id = o.time_dimension_id
           and f.account_dimension_id = o.account_dimension_id)
```

It should have been:

```
  from dbo.primary_fact f
```

A correctly formed update like this (1 day, 87k accounts) typically finishes in a minute or 2. After running for 12 minutes, I wondered what was taking so long and spotted my error.

I cancelled the query in SQL Server Management Studio which I understand will roll back all the awful I caused (can someone confirm?)

But my bigger question is:  What does the incorrectly formed query do?

---

**Update:** The cancel action finally completed, an hour and 39 minutes later.  DBAs were too slow on the kill -- just as well.

Properly formed update finished in 8 seconds.

**Second Update:** There were no values set from the original (faulty) update following the successful cancel order in SSMS.  I would interpret this to mean that any pending updates were rolled back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But my bigger question is: What does
>   the incorrectly formed query do?

It will update `dbo.primary_fact.count_of_loan_obligors` with the same value for all rows. The value will be some value from `##Obligor_Count.n`. It is hard to figure out what value that would be.

Here is a little test that basically does what you did:

```
declare @T1 table (ID int)
declare @T2 table (ID int)

insert into @T1 values (0)
insert into @T1 values (0)

insert into @T2 values (2)
insert into @T2 values (1)

update @T1
set ID = T2.ID
from @T2 as T2

select *
from @T1
```

Result:

```
ID
2
2
```

In this case `@T1` is updated with the first row in `@T2`.

Answer (score 3):

Well, first of all it looks like you could probably just re-run your query with the correct from clause instead of the staging_fact table, and it will overwrite any booboos you made. That's the good news, and the joy of working with fact tables.

Bad news is that from my experience, SSMS doesn't roll anything back unless you actually run it within a transaction, so your data is probably a big bucket of fail right now.

Hope you enjoyed that last 12 minutes of your life, because you're about to have the pleasure of doing it again.

Comment: I'm ready to run the right query but the cancel is still trying to complete and is at 1 hour and 15 minutes now.  If there's no rollback taking place, why would it still be working?  I've sent a message to our DBA to kill it.

Comment: See my second update to the post.  It seems that pending updates were rolled back.

Answer (score 2):

I worry that neither version does anything good, because they are both missing a WHERE clause connecting the table being updated with the source of the new values (f inner join o). I expect the line `WHERE primary_fact.time_dimension_id=f.time_dimension_id AND primary_fact.account_dimension_id=f.account_dimension_id` got dropped in the copy/paste.

As long as the referenced tables have the columns of those names, the join of `f` and `o` will be performed just fine. Then those values will be used to update primary_fact, either with the WHERE clause, or in some way I don't know. The UPDATE/FROM syntax is not standard SQL, but it is widely supported. Maybe SQL SERVER even adds in a default WHERE clause. Postgresql doesn't.

Comment: The "on" part of the join clause specifies the join conditions

Comment: As I read it, the `ON` clause relates the aliased version of primary_fact (f) and temp table O. Nothing is connecting f-join-o and the original primary_fact, except *maybe* some non-standard default (say, equality constraint in columns of the same name). I could validly have `UPDATE x SET x.somefield=z.randomz FROM x AS x2 JOIN z on x2.field0=z.field0 WHERE x.id=x2.id-17`

Comment: Ah.  well that was the error I was posting about, wasn't it?
update dbo.primary_fact
set count_of_loan_obligors = o.n
from dbo.primary_fact f
inner join ##Obligor_Count o
on (f.time_dimension_id = o.time_dimension_id
and f.account_dimension_id = o.account_dimension_id)
runs fine and is what was intended.

Comment: The light is going on here. SQL Server's (nonstandard) use of the `FROM` clause is different from Postgresql's (nonstandard) use of the `FROM` clause, even though they *look* the same. In SQL Server, the alias of primary_fact (f) in the FROM is really the *same* as the table being updated, so the join condition makes clear what row to update. In PG, that table is a separate copy of the original, so the rows of f and the rows of primary_fact are unrelated: you have to add a WHERE clause to match them up. Interesting.